# Where can I find out the colour for the alloys of a Nissan Micra K12 sport+ 2005?

Tags: wheels, paint

I want to refurbish my alloys and I'm looking for the spray paint colour for my alloys. Can anyone recommend a way to find this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to a paint shop. They can look up the color codes for your vehicle.

Comment: is a paint shop a specialist kind of shop versus a garage or a body shop?

Comment: Any body shop which can paint match should have the info for you.